# Sorting a list of JPQL Entities

Tags: sorting, join, entity, jpql

I've searched long and hard for an answer, but I haven't had any luck so far. I'm trying to retrieve and sort a list of objects via a JPQL query, but since the query itself uses a lot of joins between different tables, it's really difficult.

Basically, we have an entity "Person" with the fields

```
String name
List<Telephone> phones
List<Email> emails
List<Address> addresses
```

"Telephone", "Email", and "Address" are all separate Entities, each containing its own data, like a String field "number" or something similar (Address.street, Address.state). So all four of these objects are tables in the database.

I want the user to be able to sort a list of Persons by any particular data. Right now, I want to sort by any one of the following: the Person's name, the first email address in the emails list, by the street or state of the person's first address, and so on. So if a list of Persons is of the following:

```
Name     Phone Number        Street          State
Mack     555-1234            1 Main Street   WA
Andy     222-9999            2 Other Way     RI
Wendy    222-3333            3 Wrong Way     UT
```

and I want the table to be sorted by State, the list should be:

```
Name     Phone Number        Street          State
Andy     222-9999            2 Other Way     RI
Wendy    222-3333            3 Wrong Way     UT
Mack     555-1234            1 Main Street   WA
```

I want this to be done using a JPQL query so a list is already filtered and sorted when it's given to the web server to optimize performance. I must also add that I am implementing a search feature that searches all these "columns" for a particular term.

Long story short, how do I write a JPQL query such that a can obtain a list of Person objects that have been sorted for one of these columns? My implementation of "SELECT DISTINCT":

```
SELECT DISTINCT x FROM Person x, IN(x.phones) phones ORDER BY phones.number
```

doesn't work since the result table requires to have the column being sorted (which is invalid because it causes the list to not qualify as a list of Person objects), and I can't seem to use nested SELECT statements to generate the result set and then pull a list of Person objects from that. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry but I must disagree. In JPQL you can (!) sort the result set without including the sorted column in the result.

See any Hibernate example (as a promonent JPQL implementation).

Please let me know if I miss understood

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Person p 
                   JOIN p.addressList adr 
                   JOIN p.emailList eml 
                   JOIN p.phoneList phn
ORDER BY p.name, eml.emailAddress, phn.phoneNumber
```