# JPA: ordering query results by collection valued property?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I have an entity that has dollection-valued property:

```
@Entity
public class Scenario{
  ..
  @ManyToMany
  List<Category> categories;
  ..
}
```

Is there any way to query for `Scenarios` and order query results for `categories` property, something like this:

`select scenario from Scenario scenario order by scenario.category`

More precisely, we are interested in sorting for first category from each `Scenario`'s list and ignoring the rest of them. Can we do such things in JPQL/Criteria queries (eg. passing custom `Comparator` somehow)?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249467/sorting-a-list-of-jpql-entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question implies that `categories` collection has a defined order. If it's an indexed collection (i.e. it's annotated with `@OrderColumn`) and you want to sort `Scenario`s by  `name` of the first `Category`, you should be able to do the following:

```
select s from Scenario s left join s.categories c 
where index(c) = 0 order by c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

We use hibernate annotation to sort the data:

```
@Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL)
private SortedSet<Category> sections = new TreeSet<Category>();
```

Here we were using `Set` annotation as we wanted unique elements also.

```
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<Category> {

    public int compareTo(Category category) {    
        // Your implementation of compareTo
    }
}
```